# CSS Dropdown menu disappears on mouse out, I want it to stay visible when mouse is hovering over it

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, mousehover

The site I am developing is http://181.224.157.58/~differ65/hangfungsf.com/ and I am trying to get the menu to stay on when the mouse is hovering over it. I am not sure what is wrong, so can someone have a look please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the animation time of the menu is to slow.
When i hover over the menu and go down immediately it causes the menu to disappear because as i go down with my mouse the menu is not loaded yet.

You should speed up the animation or remove it to fix this issue.